# NSRegularExpression to match all string

Tags: nsregularexpression

I have more string like:

- 1 bottle of juice
- 1 bottle of pomato
- 1 package of pasta
- 1 butter

I want search a total combination of string
Like: juice, pomato, pasta

The combination is with the AND operator not with the OR operator like:
juice AND pomato AND pasta

Thanks

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the pattern for my request? Thanks